# Inserting values in a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I created a table 'records' in SQL server as

```
create table records(name varchar(20),countvalue int);
```

I used the following statement to insert a record

```
insert into records values('&name', &countvalue);
```

This statement gives me an error at & of countvalue. What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need & before countValue, I think you did mean @countValue

```
declare  @countValue int 
set @countValue = 1
insert into records values('&name', @countvalue);
```

also if you need to assign name you have to use this query

```
declare  @countValue int 
declare @name varchar(20)
set @countValue = 1
set @name = 'name'
insert into records values(@name, @countvalue);
```